# Mongoose allow a key to exist only if another is set to a certain value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which describes requests. It looks like this:

```
const requestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["available", "failed", "succeed"],
  },
  errorCode: { type: String , required : (when status is failed)},
});
```

My goal is to require `errorCode` only if `status` is set to `'failed'` and don't allow it to exist otherwise. And if possible to have it removed when status is changed to `'succeed'` for example. I can't quite find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a function to `required` to make `errorCode` required only if `status` is equal to `"failed"`, like so:

```
const requestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["available", "failed", "succeed"],
  },
  errorCode: {
    type: String,
    required: function () {
      return this.status === "failed";
    },
  },
});
```

To remove it when `status` changes to `"succeed"`, or to any other value than `"failed"`, you can use `pre` method, like so:

```
requestSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.status !== "failed") { // change it as you want
    this.errorCode = "";
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked ! But can i make it 'unallowed' when status is not failed ?

Comment: Glad I could help. I edited my answer, take a look please.